# Using oauth_common in a module to authenticate with a web service?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I'm wanting to use my Drupal 7 site to communicate with an external API that must be authenticated via 3-legged OAuth.

It seems there's a lot of documentation around about using Drupal as the OAuth provider (Via the [OAuth project](http://drupal.org/project/oauth)), but very little about using its API to do things like authenticate a Drupal site with an external web service. There's an old [complete tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/349516), but this doesn't list any of the functions that oauth_common provides, nor even really any code with how to build an OAuth session with the module.

Any help? Moreover, is there a "Drupal Way" of creating OAuth sessions?

(If it helps, I'm doing stuff with [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) and using the examples [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/introduction_to_rest_api) as a base.)

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever try to use [OAuth Connector](https://drupal.org/project/oauthconnector). It allows us to create the comsumer/application/connection to Twitter, Facebook... or another Drupal website. For my own purpose. I used that for fetch the data from Drupal 6 Services 3 by using this module in Drupal 7 and some extra code and it worked fine.

Comment: I hadn't tried that, will give it a go next OAuth project I do (Probably fairly shortly) and report back.